# PHP clean URLS (.htaccess) curl from other hardcoded application

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

One of my application has hardcoded hitting on this url

```
http://192.168.2.190/smapi/get?userid=blah&paword=blahblah&service=bahblabblah
```

Now on my CentOS machine I kept file get.php under

```
/var/www/html/smapi/
```

I wrote .htaccess file as fallow

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

I browser when I hit this URL I get error Page not found
so my application also fails

can anyone please help how can I hit file using above url

please note my calling application is already hardcoded so have to make url proper for application

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect regex in pattern of `RewriteRule`.

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /smapi/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Great @Anubhava You helped me twice in conditional rewrite.

Comment: Where can I start from learning conditional access rules.. I could have accepted answer but it says you can accept it after 10mins.

Comment: Yes I know SO has rule about 10 min now. For learning about mod_rewrite/htaccess you can refer: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html

Comment: I seen you answering regex queries in bash too.. 1UP for that too. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Ashish I answer rewrite rules questions only due to my interest in regex. Otherwise I don't have any background in server admin stuff.